# Akka Stream source code repository

Tags: scala, repository, akka-stream

It seems incredible but I can't find the `akka-stream` source code repository. The main github repo contains an [akka-stream dir](https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/master/akka-stream) but it doesn't contain the current release source.

At the moment I managed to access the code via the `-source.jar` release:
http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/typesafe/akka/akka-stream-experimental_2.11/2.0.1/akka-stream-experimental_2.11-2.0.1-sources.jar

Where is the Akka Stream source code repository?

---

**EDIT** after @ktoso comment

It seems that @ktoso updated the `akka` repository on `github`. Now the commit `1d8f6f3` and the related tag `akka-stream-and-http-experimental-2.0.1` are present.

Answer (score 2):

It appears there have been recent commits (as of Dec 30th 2015) in that dir on the latest *-dev branch https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/release-2.3-dev/akka-stream/src

EDIT:
Per Konrad 'ktoso' Malawski's comment; https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/akka-stream-and-http-experimental-2.0.1

Comment: There are commits but I haven't found one matching the source downloadable from the link I provided in the question.

Comment: That is strange, I didn't see the experimental code base anyplace

Comment: It's all on the `release-2.3-dev` branch as @Catalyst has pointed out. If you want to see the exact sources for 2.0.1 then you can look at the tag of course: https://github.com/akka/akka/releases/tag/akka-stream-and-http-experimental-2.0.1 Branching is explained in this file: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#branches-summary We'll soon move streams onto the master branch (after January 2016)

Comment: @Konrad'ktoso'Malawski I updated my answer, though I'm not sure if what I gave is the most accurate way of saying it.

Comment: The dev branch is the right answer, as you gave initially :) the tag is ok if you need specifically the sources of a given version